# facing issues when installing face_recognition module

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

I am trying to install face-recognition library using pip on Windows. However, I get an error, and the dlib package is not installed. Here is the output that I get:

```
C:\Users\Poornima>pip install face-recognition
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -make (c:\users\poornima\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -make (c:\users\poornima\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages)
Collecting face-recognition
  Using cached face_recognition-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\poornima\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from face-recognition) (1.23.5)
Collecting face-recognition-models>=0.3.0
  Using cached face_recognition_models-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Click>=6.0
  Using cached click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\poornima\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from face-recognition) (9.5.0)
Collecting dlib>=19.7
  Using cached dlib-19.24.2.tar.gz (11.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\poornima\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n
```

Comment: kind of off-topic but make sure your pip is updated (`pip install --upgrade pip`).

Comment: i've done that but still errors... legit at my breaking point

Comment: py -m, pip install dlib --upgrade  Newer version 18.24.2 released June3rd, 2023

Comment: @PoornimaNair I'm guessing you already have installed Visual C++ since it's the first thing my error displayed atfer trying to reproduce your issue ?

Comment: yeah was just going to post the solution for my issue, i did not install visual studios

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did to resolve one of many issues.

1. install visual studios and then instal visual c++
2. downgrading my python version to 3.9 worked
3. installing cmake from the website (not sure if this is a requirement or anything) , i had to install it multiple times and finally only manually downloading helped ig